# Dirac Delta and Bounded Continuous Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, mathematical-physics

I'm reading [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103901494) article and, at the begining of it, the author says: "If $(f,g) := \int dx dy f(x) v(x,y) g(y)$ is a positive-definite bounded bilinear form on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$, there exist a unique gaussian measure $d\phi_{\nu}$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ with covariance $v(x,y)$ and $$e^{-\frac{1}{2}(f,f)} = \int d\phi_{\nu}e^{i\phi(f)} \hspace{1cm} (1)$$
This follows from Minlos' [Theorem]. If $v$ is sufficiently regular, $\sup v(x,x)< \infty$ and continuity is necessary, then we can take $f(x) =\sqrt{\beta} \sum_{j=1}^{N}e_{j}\delta(x-x_{j})$ so that [...]".

**My question is:** Why is that well-justified? I agree with the afirmative concerning Minlos' Theorem but as I understand, (1) follows from the restriction of $(f,f)$ to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ (in order to use Minlos). Why can we take $f$ to be a Dirac delta if Dirac deltas are not in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$?

Comment: Did you mean $e^{-\frac{1}{2}(f,f)} = \int_{\phi \in S'(R^3)} e^{i\phi(f)}d\phi$ (where $\phi(f)$ means applying the distribution $\phi$ to the Schwartz function $f$). If those things are sufficiently regular you can restrict the integral to the dense subspace $S(R^3)$ where $\phi(\delta)$ is well-defined

Comment: Yes, it is exaclty that. But if I restrict the integral to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$, can I take $f$ to be a Diract delta? How does the Dirac delta belong to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$?

Comment: It is not, but assuming everything is sufficiently continuous, you can extend $(.,.)$  by continuity to $S'$, same for $\phi(f)$, restrict the integral to $S(R^3)$, obtaining $e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\delta,\delta)} = \int_{\phi \in S(R^3)} e^{i\phi(\delta)}d\phi$, that's the spirit but I don't know what you need exactly. If you need to prove those things then you should use that the Hermite functions give an isomorphism from $S(R)$ to the rapidly decreasing sequence and $S'(R)$ to the polynomially bounded sequences so that those things become concrete series.

Comment: But this should imply that $v$ is in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ right?

Comment: $(.,.)$ is continuous well-defined on $S'$ iff $v$ is in $S(R^6)$ but here you only need to extend $(.,.)$ to the compactly supported order $0$ distributions like $\delta$, that $v$ is continuous is enough.